# How do you create a SQL server for asp on azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have an asp website with a SQL server that for some reason doesn't get passed along when I publish the solution. How do I get a SQL server running on azure? I've looked it up and tried following a couple of tutorials but there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of information on it.

Comment: How far did you get? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started/

Comment: I don't want to purchase a SQL server I want to just have it on the web app

Comment: If you want the SQL Server to run in Azure you have to provision it and pay for it...

Answer (score 1):

To get an SQL server running on Azure, you have two solutions :

1. PaaS solution with Azure SQL Database
2. IaaS solution by using an SQL server Instance on a dedicated virtual machine

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-paas-vs-sql-server-iaas/) is a nice link explaining benefits and limitations of both solution.

Regards